# Disable Mouseleave in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to display a tooltip when the `mouseover` event is triggered on `.iconImage`:

```
 $('body').append('<span id="note-tooltip-wrapper"><a href="#" class="close">Slet <img src="/images/note-close-icon.png"></a><span class="content"></span><span class="bottom"><a href="#" class="edit">Ret</a></span></span>');
    $('.show .iconimage').wrap("<span class='note-tip-wrapper'></span>").closest('.note-tip-wrapper').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
    $('.show .iconimage').mouseover(function () {
        var $tipheight = $(this).closest('.note-tip-wrapper').find('.show .iconimage').height();
        var $tipwidth = $(this).closest('.note-tip-wrapper').find('.show .iconimage').width();
        var $html = $(this).closest('p.show').next('.longnote').html();
        $('#note-tooltip-wrapper').appendTo($(this).closest('.note-tip-wrapper')).fadeIn(300).css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'left': 0, 'top': 0, 'z-index': '10000' }).find('.content').html($html);
        $('#note-tooltip-wrapper .save').trigger('click');
    });
    $('#note-tooltip-wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(300);
    });
    //$('#note-tooltip-wrapper .close').live('click', function () {
    //    $(this).closest('#note-tooltip-wrapper').hide();
    //});
    $('#note-tooltip-wrapper .edit').live('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('edit').addClass('save').text('spare');
        var $html = $(this).closest('#note-tooltip-wrapper').find('.content .editNote').html();
        $(this).closest('#note-tooltip-wrapper').find('.content .editNote').html('<textarea cols="5" rows="5">' + $html + '</textarea>');
    });
    $('#note-tooltip-wrapper .save').live('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('save').addClass('edit').text('ret');
        var $html = $(this).closest('#note-tooltip-wrapper').find('.content textarea').val();
        //console.log($html)
        $(this).closest('#note-tooltip-wrapper').find('.content .editNote').html($html);
        $(this).closest('p.show').next('.longnote').find('.editNote').html($html);
    });
```

This code displays the tooltip properly on `mouseover` and `mouseout`, but I'd like to trigger `mouseout` when `.edit` is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger `mouseleave` programmatically:

```
$('#note-tooltip-wrapper').trigger('mouseleave');
```

Comment: Where I place this Code.in .edit .live click or?

Comment: I just Put Like This

$('#note-tooltip-wrapper .edit').live('click', function () {
$('#note-tooltip-wrapper').trigger('mouseleave');
        $(this).removeClass('edit').addClass('save').text('spare');
        var $html = $(this).closest('#note-tooltip-wrapper').find('.content .editNote').html();
        $(this).closest('#note-tooltip-wrapper').find('.content .editNote').html('<textarea cols="5" rows="5">' + $html + '</textarea>');
    });

Comment: That *should* work. Also, `live` has been deprecated and was removed from jQuery 1.9, use `on` instead.